# CSS ul userlist formatting

Tags: css

I am trying to break away from using tables in my formatting, and am trying out using userlist html tags `<ul>`

Say I have a panel with 10 controls, and I want a 3 columns display, therefore 3 controls in each row, and a total of 4 rows for 10 controls.

Should I use 4 different `<ul>` or should I just stack them inside one `<ul>`

Please tell me the advantages and disadvantages

Thanks

Comment: `<ul>` stands for unordered list, and not userlist.

Comment: He could be formatting a **userlist** *with an* **unordered list**...

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? When I try to visualize your explanation, I keep coming up with 12 controls (4 rows by 3 columns).

Comment: Sounds like the last row only contains one control though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantages of putting them in 1

- One place to maintain
- Is semantic

The advantage of more than 1

- *could* be easier to style.

If you put them in 1 unordered list, and then wanted 3 columns, you could do this

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden; /* force it to expand to floated elements */
}

ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 32%; /* slightly less as browsers can make a muck of percentages */
    float: left;

}
```

### Update

From [George IV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50214/george-iv) in the comments, see above.

This will float them left to right, in 3 columns. You could also try using inline-block to achieve this, however it's implementation is a little more difficult to get cross browser.

Comment: you may have to go a little less than 33% (like 32.9%) for true cross-browser support.

Answer (score 0):

'ul' stands for unordered list and is used for listing. Instead use 'div'

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="control">
  <div class="control">
  <div class="control">
</div>
```

and use the CSS

```
#container {
width: 100%;
}

#control {
width: 33%;
float: left;
}
```